# (iOS7) Scroll to cursor in UITextView in UITableView in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a problem since I updated to iOS7.

I have base `UIScrollView` horizontally and there is `UITableView` on it
(looks like a navigation style).
And I `addChild UITextView` on `UITableView` not on the cells.

And it scrolled to `UITextView`'s cursor when typing keyboard. And it works greatly until iOS 6 but not since updating iOS7.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add some screenshots ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have three UITableView. and they are on UIScrollView which is scrolling horizonly.
and There is UITextView on each UITableView. that's it.

Comment: I picture is worth 1000 words :) also do add some codes. So that we can know where the problem might have been !

Comment: I put a bounty on this as I'm having a similar problem, namely that when the user types into a auto-sizing UITextView inside a UITableViewCell, the tableview doesn't scroll to show the cursor (well, it sounds related to me!)

Comment: can you add some code or screenshots?

Answer (score 6):

Handle `textViewDidChangeSelection` in UITextViewDelegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange];
}
```

The exact solution depends on your application, you can handle by subclassing UITextView but I would prefer a decorator pattern here (on UITextViewDelegate protocol).

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created your XIBs in xCode4 and now trying to open it in xCode5?
If yes than please check your XIBs properly as Xcode5 updates older xCode 4.x XIBs and sometimes it results in a unpredicted output.. I faces the same issues when all my views just disappears after opening it in Xcode5..

Also do try to change the settings of the xib in File Inspector to open in xcode 4.x and view as ios6.1 and earlier and see if it changes anything..